# How to make a class persistent capable

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdo

I am trying to create a class whose code snippet is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import com.objy.db.app.ooObj;


import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;

@PersistenceCapable
public class Student extends ooObj implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Now, the program is not even getting compiled, as it says t cannot recognize ooObj class, and without this, the logger returns the following:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "project2.Student" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.]]
```

Could someone please suggest how to either make the class persistent capable or some maven dependency to use ooObj.

Comment: Are you sure that the jar file is in classpath or build path of IDE ?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701565/google-app-engine-classnotpersistencecapableexception?rq=1

Comment: As suggested in answer, you need to search maven dependency for that annotation and add to your POM file.

Comment: You make a class PersistenceCapable by ENHANCING it; your documentation would tell you this. And why are you bastardising your code by putting Objectivity references in it (ooObj)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a Google search for "com.objy.db.app.ooObj" and try to find the missing dependency yourself!

I guess you need to download Objectivity/DB for Java: http://support.objectivity.com/downloads

Comment: I tried on "search.maven.org" and also did a google search, but there was nothing related

Comment: Thanks all! It works now, some plugins were missing.